# Question by minors about relationships

Tags: discussion

There was a question ( [this one](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/6953/turning-people-down-for-a-relationship) , now on hold ) which was asked by someone who said they were a *15 year old*.  Is there (or should there be) a policy about giving advice on this subject (relationships) to a minor ?

That particular question does not have any overt sexual context, by the way, but I'd also appreciate comments on whether that does or should make a difference to such a policy.

Comment: Why not? Can you explain why you think we should avoid this?

Comment: It's a two fold issue.  Firstly, I'd wonder about the legal soundness of a site like this giving such advice - it may be opening up the site to legal sanctions or lawsuits.  Secondly, is it ethical for strangers on the internet to be giving advice of this sort to minors ?  There isn't, as I see it, a great deal of difference between a minor getting advice from people on this site and a minor stopping people on the street at random to ask for this advice.  With adult posters we can assume they know what they're doing in asking - with minors this is very dubious, I think.

Comment: Comment from a 15-year-old here - I'm not sure why you think that a teenager doesn't know what they're doing in asking questions here. Are you saying that we're too young to understand what posting on the Internet means?

Comment: @ArwenUndómiel As I explained in a previous comment, there are legal considerations from the point of view of adults answering question like these from minors.  I'm simply seeking clarification from the community so we have some reasonable basis for a policy - that's what Meta is for.  Keep in mind that minors vary from cynical as hardened politicians to very, very naive - there's no one single type of minor.  Legally and morally adults have to be a great deal more careful "talking" to minors that with other adults.  I'm asking about adult responsibilities in this case, not yours.

Answer (score 5):

I think the best way to handle these questions is to answer to the best of our ability, the same way we would answer any other relationship question, with the minor caveat of making an effort to be age appropriate.

That age appropriate piece is something that's a little harder to quantify. I almost just want to say, if you don't know what that means and need it explained, please don't answer questions from younger users. More or less, if you've ever raised kids yourself, treat these questions with the care and consideration that you would if you were talking to your own kid.

Try to be a responsible adult/human and be nice, but try to keep in mind that you're talking to someone who doesn't have the experience and likely doesn't have the judgement of someone who's had some experience.

Do your absolute best to answer the young ones in a safe and healthy way. Try to keep in mind what you were like at that age, what was important to you, what mistakes did you make, and how did you learn from them. There's a pretty big difference between "You should do this..." and "This is what I did, and this is what I learned from it..."

And please try to be gentle, they're kids after all.

Answer (score 4):

Since the user claims to be 15 years old, I suppose they're permitted to ask questions here. We just have to write our answers accordingly. Also consider their location, culture, etc. Or close it, if it's not answerable.

We do not have any means of verifying a user's age. If in case they claim to be under 13, the usual approach would be to take it at face value and quickly delete their account on the site.

See also: [How do I use Stack Exchange if I'm under 13 years old?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/61770/309993)

Answer (score 4):

I think situations like these require special consideration by answerers, but I don't think they should be disallowed. Give advice there like on any other question, but take mind of the potential implications of your advice.

The only point is that if they're under 13, that has to be reported to SE staff, which have to delete their account quickly.

One thing that is important though is that on questions like these you linked, we need to be especially wary of and react quickly to troll and rude answers, since they might have further implications then just being rude, too.